# customizing string item in string array

Tags: android

My below xml lines from string-array is not formatted.

```
   <string-array
    name= "viewrequest">
     <item><font size = "20"><b>"Request 1 Title:"<u>"STATUS"</u></b></font> 
    <font size="12"><b> "\nCreated:"</b> DD/MM/YY
       "\nDescription : the lazy brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    <b>" \n \nUpdated:"</b> "DD/MM/YY" 
        <b>"\nUpdated by : "</b>"XYZ"</font></item>
    </string-array>
```

can anyone helpme how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can take the value in to string and
format the string to form an array using the pattern match.
This is how I do when I get array from wsdl.

```
String r = ”anyType{string=10054; string=10055; string=10056; string=10035; string=10052; string=10036; string=10037; string=10038; }”;
String temp = r.replaceAll(";\\s", ",").replaceAll("string=", " ")
.replace("anyType{", "").replace(",}", "");
String[] fulname = temp.split(",\\s+");
```

'r' is a string array

r =”anyType{string=10054; string=10055; string=10056; string=10035; string=10052; string=10036; string=10037; string=10038; }”

step 2- Then creating a String variable called temp where I am removing all the unwanted characters using the replaceAll function. after removing unwanted characters temp looks like this

temp=”10054, 10055, 10056, 10035, 10052, 10036, 10037, 10038″

step3- Finally created a string array called ‘fulname’ and split the modified string with ‘,\s’ Array fulname after split looks like this

fulname = [ 10054, 10055, 10056, 10035, 10052, 10036, 10037, 10038]

This will work fine because all the wsdl array return the same type of string with same unwanted characters

Hope you understood
Good Luck

Comment: i want to set font size for particular item in string arrayin xml .but my above posted code doesn't work . why